# Is it natural to say "he tripped in the gap" in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

There are a lot of gaps in floors like this on construction sites:

[image]

And there is a good chance that a worker might trip **...?**

I don't know what preposition I should fill in the dotted line.

We often say "**trip over/ on sth**" and something here is not a hole or looks like a hole or gap.

For example, *Someone will trip over that cable.*

Is it correct to say "the worker tripped over the gap" or "the worker tripped on the gap" or "the worker tripped in the gap"?

Comment: It's fine to say "trip over a gap" and  "trip over a hole".

Comment: Normally, you ***trip*** when your foot ***hits*** something you weren't expecting, so losing your footing because of an actual ***void*** underfoot is inherently awkward to express (as I'm sure OP knows perfectly well, since he specializes in finding these awkward contexts). At least a couple of writers have resorted to [*tripped on **the edge of** the hole,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tripped+on+the+edge+of+the+hole%22) for lack of any more suitable phrasing. But there a half a dozen instances of ***tripped on a hole***, and more for ***...over...***

Comment: Or 'caught his foot in the gap'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (and also Kate Bunting) Just in case you weren't aware, but I'm sure you are, your comments are allowing users to gain some serious reputation in their answers. Once in a while, it doesn't harm anyone, but earning rep thanks to your contributions in the comment section  has been going on for several months. At the very least, answers inspired by highly up-voted comments should not allow users to earn rep.  Posting a community wiki post is (or used to be) the fairest thing to do.

Comment: Or "He stumbled when the toe of his shoe got snagged  in a gap in the flooring."  (got caught, got snagged : American English).

Comment: @Mari-LouA   When there are many ways of saying something, it seems better to suggest one of them as a comment than to present  it as answer.

Comment: More than once FF and KB have left answers in comments and more often than not, one or more users have posted answers prompted by those comments. As a result they earn reputation. FF doesn't comment suggestions, his comments do not ask for clarifications or more detail, they are, more often than not, proper answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I didn't think that suggesting a possible alternative merited being posted as an official answer.

Comment: @KateBunting why not? It's a very good suggestion and there are four upvotes agreeing with it, including mine. What's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually speak of 'tripping over' something that projects out of the ground, though it isn't obviously wrong to speak of tripping over a hole. I would suggest **He caught his foot in the gap** as a more idiomatic alternative.